# How to adapt collating SQL_EBCDIC037_CP1_CS_AS to match iSeries CCSID 500?

Tags: sql-server, db2, ibm-midrange, collation

We are currently migrating a Java application from DB2 on iSeries (= AS/400) to MS SQL Server, and we must fully respect the sorting order of CCSID 500 as used on iSeries.

SQL Server provides a collation named `SQL_EBCDIC037_CP1_CS_AS`, which is very close to what we need: EBCDIC037 when compared to CCSID 500  has differences in sorting order only for characters  `[`, `!`, `]`, `^`, `¢`, `¬`, and `|`.

We would like to correct thoses discrepancies by creating a new collating sequence derived from `SQL_EBCDIC037_CP1_CS_AS`.

How can we do that? Our log research did not bring any suitable answer.
Should we do using that at Windows Server locale and adapt the current Server locale?